# How to create a python function for the below requirement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function, user-defined-functions

I need to create a python function for which I need to subtract a value from previous row and the first row for all the account id will be 1. I attach the image of excel file need to calculate Column D as per the working in the excel sheet.

I will be having the values for column A,B,C and from this need to calculate Column D as per the working in the excel sheet.

Formula to arrive Column D is D[i-1]-C[i]-B[i].

Note: For all the account id the first row need to be subtracted by 1 as indicated in column D4.

Formula for D5 Cell is D4-C5-B5 and D6 Cell is D5-C6-B6 and for cell D7 is D6-C7-B7 and so on.

[image: Data]

[image: Sample Data]

Thanks,
Karthik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 0.0011, 0.0350],
    [2, 0.0017, 0.0370],
    [3, 0.0032, 0.0390],
    [4, 0.0055, 0.0430],
], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df['D'] = 1 - (df.C + df.B).cumsum()
df
```

prints

| index | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0.0011 | 0.035 | 0.9639 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.0017 | 0.037 | 0.9252 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.0032 | 0.039 | 0.883 |
| 3 | 4 | 0.0055 | 0.043 | 0.8345 |

Comment: How to apply group by to the above code as the same logic needs to be applied to multiple account id. In the shared example there is only one account id what if we need to subtract the first obeservation by 1 for multiple account id's.